# How to add heart icon in MaterialCSS?

Tags: css, icons

I can not find **heart Icon** in materializecss.
so I am thinking about solution using an heart image instead of using fontawesome.

Is it ok? Please give me a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It has been existed. But it is not called "heart".
Please search by "favorite" keyword and you can see 2 icon that you're finding.
[image]